# Enclose greek sentence between tag or find and replace part of sentence that contains greek characters

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I am trying to find a way to enclose sentences using greek characters in special tags (in this case LaTeX but it doesn't matter). So given my input text:

```
inputtext = "some english text ῍Ενθεσις τοῦ Ψαλτής and then english again"
```

I would like to achieve this:

```
results = "some english text \textgreek{῍Ενθεσις τοῦ Ψαλτής} and then english again"
```

After some hours I came up with this solution that almost work:

```
import re 
inputtext = "some english text ῍Ενθεσις τοῦ Ψαλτής and then english again" 
t = re.findall('[α-ωΑ-Ω]',inputtext) 
beg = inputtext.find(t[0]) 
end = inputtext.rfind(t[-1]) + 1 
results = "".join((inputtext[:beg]+"\textgreek{"+inputtext[beg:end]+"}"+inputtext[end:]))


In [50]: results                                                                                  
Out[50]: 'some english text ῍\textgreek{Ενθεσις τοῦ Ψαλτής} and then english again'
```

Then the topical question arose to my mind, is there a better solution? Maybe using only regex? **The current solution seems to ignore the polytonic greek characters `῍` and of course it works only if there is one greek sentence per sentence.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module:

```py
>>> s = "some english text ῍Ενθεσις τοῦ Ψαλτής and then english again"
>>> regex.sub(r'\p{Greek}+(\s+\p{Greek}+)*', r'\textgreek{\g<0>}', s)
'some english text \textgreek{῍Ενθεσις τοῦ Ψαλτής} and then english again'
```

This is based on given sample, not sure how want to deal with characters like non-greek punctuations.

If [Greek_and_Coptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_and_Coptic) and [Greek_Extended](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_Extended) have all the characters you want to match, then you can manually construct the character range and thus use `re` module itself:

```py
>>> s = "some english text ῍Ενθεσις τοῦ Ψαλτής and then english again"
>>> re.sub(r'[\u0370-\u03ff\u1f00-\u1fff]+(\s+[\u0370-\u03ff\u1f00-\u1fff]+)*', r'\textgreek{\g<0>}', s)
'some english text \textgreek{῍Ενθεσις τοῦ Ψαλτής} and then english again'
```

Comment: That seems a really good solution much better than mine, Thanks a lot!I did not know that  \p{Greek} finds all the words with Greek unicode, I will wait a couple of days before accepting the answer.